# QNap Nas-Finding drive order for Raid 6

Tags: raid6

I have a Qnap 10 bay Nas that had two separate raid setups in it. I know that the Raid6 ran from left to right 1~5 slots, and then the Raid5 ran from slots 6~8. They both had hot spare drives in slot 9 for the Raid6 and slot 10 for the Raid5. I am only interested in finding the drive order for the Raid6, the drives in the raid6 are all WD 2TB drives and the Raid5 were all WD 5TB drives. So I know which drives belong to the Raid6 but don't know which is the hot spare, or which order the 5 disks go. Someone in the work place decided to pull the drives out without numbering or recording the serials or any type of documenting in order to put them back in the correct order. The system is EXT3. The data on the drives is not corrupted or at least wasn't prior to the drives being pulled, and the raid6 was working properly ie. no drive failures or problems. So in the end the question is how can I get the drive order information from the drives themselves?

I have been looking online for days and days now, but most information I find relates to Raid5. I don't have an extra disk controller at the time, and am wondering if there is a way to hook each drive up by itself to a Windows7 machine and extract the information I need.

Answer (score 0):

A QNAP NAS uses `mdadm` to build the RAID. `mdadm` uses metadata on the drive to identify it, so the physical sequence of the bays/ports doesn't matter.

However, depending on how the NAS exactly boots (I'm not sure of that), the sequence *might* matter. If you examine the drives' [RAID superblocks](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_superblock_formats) you should be able to reconstruct the sequence from there.